# WSO2 DAS + Clustering APIM with mysql

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

1. My APIM version is 1.10.0 and DAS is 3.0.1.
2. At first ,I deploy no Clustering APIM + DAS with mysql. the stats shows good.
3. Then,I clustering APIM into publisher、store、keymanager and gateway.Configured APIM and DAS order [this article](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+RDBMS#PublishingAPIRuntimeStatisticsUsingRDBMS-ConfiguringWSO2APIManager),when I invoke an api , gateway node then show error

> ```
> [2016-10-13 11:13:54,775] ERROR - APIMgtUsageHandler Cannot publish event. null
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.publishEvent(APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.java:124)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler.handleRequest(APIMgtUsageHandler.java:169)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:322)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:86)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:65)
>         at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:295)
>         at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
>         at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>         at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:317)
>         at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:149)
>         at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> [2016-10-13 11:13:54,807] ERROR - APIMgtResponseHandler Cannot publish response event. null
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.publishEvent(APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.java:140)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler.mediate(APIMgtResponseHandler.java:211)
>         at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:84)
>         at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
>         at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
>         at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:335)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:86)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:52)
>         at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:295)
>         at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
>         at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
>         at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>         at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:251)
>         at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

4. Then i change the way of DAS configuration. Following [this blog](http://rukspot.com/configure_wso2_apim_analytics_using_xml.html) ,i configured all the api-manager.xml,there is no error and no stats.And store node show info:

> ```
> [2016-10-18 11:31:39,131]  INFO - ReceiverGroup Resending the failed published data...
> [2016-10-18 11:31:44,134]  WARN - AccessConfiguration Error loading properties from file: access-log.properties
> [2016-10-18 11:31:44,207]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after : 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout
> ```

5. I google the reason ,in [wso2 jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4307),they say this is not a bug.

But I cannot wait for my stats for hours.Did I configure something wrong?

Reguards.

Comment: can you browse the DAS table by login to DAS management console. You can browse the table org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.request in the Data explorer menu. Also make sure you have deploy the Capp in the <DAS>/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/ dir

Comment: there is no data in the table org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.request under Data explorer menu,except ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_WORKFLOW table gets a few data.Under <DAS>/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/ is API_Manager_Analytics_RDBMS.car.  No distributed APIM,I can get stats from publisher and store. when distributed, there is no stats

Answer (score 0):

Seems in store node, data are publishing are enabled and working. But gateway node data not publishing. Please try to verify the gateway node configuration. Also check gateway node can access the DAS node.

Comment: Thanks, ruks. The configuration on store and gateway node`s api-manager.xml is the same .Is there any other configuration? How can I check gateway node can access the DAS node?In my step 2, can I prove DAS is available？Or the DAS receiver didnot receive message?

Comment: I use NO distributed APIM with DAS, after invoke api ,There is stats.Then I change APIM into DISTRIBUTED , then I invoke another api , the stats shows SubscriberCount but no Hits .

Comment: But DAS management console in the Data explorer menu,I can not find the new invoke api DATA. Is the gateway cannot send or DAS cannot receive?And how to slove?