# API usages are not recorded when integrating WSO2 APIM1.10.0 cluster with WSO2 DAS 3.0.1 cluster

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I am using [WSO2 Kubernetes Artifacts](https://docs.wso2.com/display/KA100/WSO2+Kubernetes+Artifacts+Documentation) to build WSO2 APIM 1.10.0 cluster.

Here is my configuration :

- **[api-key-manager.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mike00151/THMM/master/api-key-manager.yaml)**
- **[api-publisher.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mike00151/THMM/master/api-publisher.yaml)**
- **[api-store.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mike00151/THMM/master/api-store.yaml)**
- **[gateway-manager.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mike00151/THMM/master/gateway-manager.yaml)**

With the above configurations, APIM cluster works fine on my kubernetes environment. Then I want to get statistics from WSO2 DAS 3.0.1. Here is my steps.

1. Open admin-dashboard page.
2. Fill in DAS information.
3. Save configuration.
4. Publish the sample API and subscribe it.
5. Invoke the created API.

Though API returns the correct result, I can not see any statistics from DAS page. Table `ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_REQUEST` is also empty. Moreover, there are some exceptions in gateway container as follows:

```
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119378825Z [2017-02-02 10:17:05,118] ERROR - APIMgtUsageHandler Cannot publish event. null
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119410635Z java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119416221Z at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.publishEvent(APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.java:124)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119421345Z at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler.handleRequest(APIMgtUsageHandler.java:169)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119425422Z at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:322)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119429269Z at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:86)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119432713Z at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:65)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119444539Z at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:295)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119448051Z at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119451190Z at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119454693Z at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:317)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119457708Z at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:149)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119460675Z at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119463755Z at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119466748Z at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.119470008Z at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292159023Z [2017-02-02 10:17:05,291] ERROR - APIMgtResponseHandler Cannot publish response event. null
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292186860Z java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292191607Z at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.publishEvent(APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.java:140)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292196079Z at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler.mediate(APIMgtResponseHandler.java:211)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292199487Z at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:84)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292202823Z at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292206246Z at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292210195Z at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292213976Z at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292216990Z at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:335)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292220203Z at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:86)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292223430Z at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:52)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292226576Z at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:295)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292229762Z at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292232861Z at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292236007Z at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292238952Z at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:251)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292252632Z at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292256191Z at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292259335Z at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2017-02-02T10:17:05.292262507Z at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The problem may be same as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104970/wso2-das-clustering-apim-with-mysql), but I don't see solution.

**Edit 1**

I also did 2 experiments as follow.

First:

1. Create a ubuntu pod.
2. Install WSO2 APIM 1.10.0 on the ubuntu pod container.
3. Open the admin-dashboard page and fill in DAS information.
4. Publish the sample API and subscribe it.
5. Invoke the created API.

Which works fine. I can see the statistics from DAS page.

Second :

1. Jump into APIM container.
2. Using telnet to verify thrift port of DAS cluster.

The thrift port was accessible for APIM cluster.

According to the exception, I think that might be caused by configurations missing in gateway container?

Comment: This looks like a connectivity issue. Did you check the connectivity from gateway nodes to DAS nodes? When publishing events from gateway nodes to DAS nodes, it uses the thrift protocol. I think this will work if you use a Kube Service which has a single container. When you have multiple containers, K8 service will load balance and it could cause issues. Thrift is point to point TCP connection.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please find the update above.

Comment: Is that your api is non-auth API?

Comment: uh...what do you mean `non-auth API`?